# node definition is not being enforced

Tags: puppet

I'm trying to get ramped up on Puppet (2.7.x), but I'm encountering some strange behavior with the node definitions.  From the documentation, I thought that the 'default' node was a catchall for any node which wasn't explicitly matched elsewhere.  However, what I'm seeing is that the default seems to apply even where there is an exact match.  For example, I have the following in site.pp:

```
import "services/*"
node "cuda-farm-ljf1" {
        include hello
}
node default {
        include ntp
}
```

The only thing in hello.pp is:

```
class hello {
        notify {
                "hello test":
        }
}
```

What I'd expect is that the 'ntp' class will *not* apply to the 'cuda-farm-ljf1' node, however that isn't the behavior that I'm
seeing.  Even if I completely uninstall ntp on that node, its reinstalled & started the next time it syncs with the master.  Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are missing the obvious...
When you include classes under `node default` it applies to all the puppet client machines. 
Learn more about `node default`.

http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/2.7/reference/lang_node_definitions.html

Comment: Hrmm, I actually read that page originally, but I still don't quite follow where it states that a default node applies to all nodes.  I think I'm still not understanding something somewhere.  The only section that seems semi-relevant is here: http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/2.7/reference/lang_node_definitions.html#matching

Comment: I tried what you suggested (even going so far as to remove the default node altogether from site.pp), yet ntp is still being enabled.

Comment: are you sure puppet agent is crashing and then caching some old catalog where it is directed to install ntp ?

Comment: I'm sure its not crashing.  I've run the agent manually iwth the --test option, and it completes with no errors.  And other changes that I've applied to the manifests are successfully applied on the agents.